# Gorm handle HasOne relationship

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I have a problem with GORM and MySQL. I have this structure:

```
type Users struct {
ID          string
Balance     Balances
Model
}

type Model struct {
CreatedAt time.Time
UpdatedAt time.Time
DeletedAt *time.Time
}

type Balances struct {
UID     string `gorm:"foreignkey:ID;unique_index"`
USD     int
}
```

I would like to SELECT users which have the USD field of their balance greater than 0. How can I do that?

Anyway, `db.Find(&users)` get all users, but not their balance. In fact, the query executed is: `SELECT * FROM users  WHERE users.deleted_at IS NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.Joins()` to join `Users` with `Balances` then use condition using `.Where()`

```
user := Users{}
db.Joins("JOIN balances ON balances.uid = users.id").Where("balances.usd > 0").Find(&user)
```

**Update:**
Try to correct your relation to preload balance

```
type Users struct {
ID          string 
Balance     Balances `gorm:"foreignkey:UID;association_foreignkey:ID"`
Model
}

type Balances struct {
UID     string `gorm:"unique_index"`
USD     int
}
```

Comment: This worked, but my Balance structure in Users is empty. Is there a way to have usd values in that?

Comment: @Rockietto you can use  `.Preload("Balances")` before  `.Join()` to load banlance also

Comment: Just tried this
`db.Debug().Preload("Balances").Joins("JOIN balances ON balances.uid = users.id").Where("balances.usd > 0").Find(&users)`

but returns `can't preload field Balances for structs.Users`

Comment: Tried this `db.Debug().Preload("Balance").Joins("JOIN balances ON balances.uid = users.id").Where("balances.usd > 0").Find(&users)`, got this error `can't preload field Balance for structs.Users`. I also tried to put `Preload("Balance")` before `Find` with the same error.

Comment: May be relational problem between User and Balance

Comment: Updated my answer